# Mixin constructors nested pack expansion

Tags: c++, inheritance, variadic-templates, virtual, mixins

I am trying to implement a Mixin class, and facing some problems:

This is what I have at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        cout << "default ctor" << endl;
    }
    
    Base(int i, string s)
        :i_(i)
            ,s_(s)
    {
        cout << "i: " << i << " s:" << s << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void handle() {};
    
    int i_;
    string s_;
};

struct Der1 : virtual public Base
{
    using Base::Base;
};

struct Der2 : virtual public Base
{
    using Base::Base;
};

template<class... Mixin>
class MixinVisitor : public Mixin... {
public:
  template <typename... Args>
  MixinVisitor(Args&&... args) : Mixin(std::forward<Args>(args)...)...
  {
  }

};



int main()
{
    MixinVisitor<Der1, Der2> m(10, "var");
    cout << m.i_ << endl;
}
```

I want all the classes to be called with the parameters specified in the `MixinVisitor` constructor.
`Der1` and `Der2` inherit virtually from the same Base class.

The code I have now compiles with Clang, but fails with GCC.
The behavior with Clang is not what I expect though, as I see as output only the default constructor being called.

Gcc error is as follows:

```
prog.cc:44:68: error: invalid use of pack expansion expression
   44 |   MixinVisitor(Args&&... args) : Mixin(std::forward<Args>(args)...)...
      |                                                                    ^~~
1
```

Moreover the output is not what I am expecting, and that might be due to virtual inheritance.

I only see the default ctor being called:

```
default ctor
4204112
```

How can I force the proper constructor to be called?

edit:
thank to the comments, there's a workaround for the gcc problem:

```
  MixinVisitor(Args&&... args) : Mixin{std::forward<Args>(args)...}...
```

however I'd still like to know why the correct constructor is not called

Comment: Seems gcc bug..

Comment: @Jarod42 seems like, and on top of that, even with clang it doesn't do what I expect it to do, with the base class being default constructed

Comment: @rustyx I just tried that but I still see the default ctor being called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26099873/9072753 . `MixinVisitor(Args&&... args) : Mixin{std::forward<Args>(args)...}..., Base{args...} {}` seems to work vv

Comment: You can work around the (presumably) gcc bug by using braces instead `Mixin{std::forward<Args>(args)...}...`. This way both compilers give consistent results at least.

Comment: nice catch @cigien and @KamilCuk on the `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCC error `invalid use of pack expansion expression` is a bug [#88580](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88580). Seems to be a regression in GCC 10.

As mentioned in the comments, changing `:Mixin(std::forward<Args>(args)...)...` to `:Mixin{std::forward<Args>(args)...}...` solves the issue.

Regarding why the default `Base` constructor is called: the virtual base class's constructor is called directly by the most derived class's constructor. In this case, `MixinVisitor` directly calls the `Base` constructor, and since you don't mention which one to call, the default one is called. This is how virtual inheritance works (see also the [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-ctors)).

If you want to call `Base(int i, string s)` instead, specify it explicitly, e.g. like this:

```
template<class... Mixin>
class MixinVisitor : public Mixin... {
public:
  template <typename... Args>
  MixinVisitor(Args&&... args)
      : Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Mixin{std::forward<Args>(args)...}...
  {
  }

  . . .
```

I don't know about your specific use-case, but a virtual base is usually a very basic boilerplate class with a default ctor, so as not to restrict usage unnecessarily. This way the mixins can have ctors that do not depend on the base.